# Redirecting search to specific templates with $_GET["post_type"]

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I'm using `$_GET["post_type"]` to direct my search to the correct templates and have used the following:

```
<?php $search_refer = $_GET["post_type"];
if ($search_refer == 'news') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-news.php'); }
elseif ($search_refer == 'members') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-members.php'); }; ?>
```

I need to add another `elseif` to this where the search refer is news but the posts have the status "future". Is it possible to do that?

The current news search refer needs to only show posts with the status "published".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check status in your `search-news.php` template. And if `$_GET['status']` is equal to `future`, create custom loop for it. Your `search-news.php` could look something like this:

```
if ( $_GET['status'] == 'future' ) :

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'   => 'news',
        'post_status' => 'future',
        // else arguments ...
    ) ); 

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        // do stuff ...
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

else :

    // do normal news stuff ...

endif;
```